# method declared in struct in C++ (STL)

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to understand the syntax used in STL for a class.  Our teacher pointed us to this website (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) where I copied the code below:

```
struct ltstr
{
  bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
  }
};

int main()
{
  map<const char*, int, ltstr> months;

  months["january"] = 31;
  months["february"] = 28;
  months["march"] = 31;
  months["april"] = 30;
  months["may"] = 31;
  months["june"] = 30;
  months["july"] = 31;
  months["august"] = 31;
  months["september"] = 30;
  months["october"] = 31;
  months["november"] = 30;
  months["december"] = 31;

  cout << "june -> " << months["june"] << endl;
  map<const char*, int, ltstr>::iterator cur  = months.find("june");
  map<const char*, int, ltstr>::iterator prev = cur;
  map<const char*, int, ltstr>::iterator next = cur;    
  ++next;
  --prev;
  cout << "Previous (in alphabetical order) is " << (*prev).first << endl;
  cout << "Next (in alphabetical order) is " << (*next).first << endl;
}
```

I did not know you could declare methods in structs.  How does that work?

I'm assuming that with it, when you declare the map named months, using the luster in the Compare field of a map alphabetizes the map.  But still unsure about how it works with the struct syntax.  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++, a `struct` is really just a class whose default access specifier is `public` and which inherits publicly by default.

In other words,

```
struct ltstr
{
    // ...
};
```

is equivalent to

```
class ltstr
{
public:
    // ...
};
```

If you want to, you can make parts of your struct `protected` or `private`, too.

The reason that `struct` is still in C++, even though it's redundant, is backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Alexandre: Good point -- I've incorporated this into the answer.

Comment: @Alexandre: Oooops... should have checked. This means the two code snippets are not just almost equivalent but exactly equivalent...

Answer (score 1):

in C++ structs are classes with public members by default

Comment: You mean, with public members by default

Comment: And inherit as public by default.

Comment: -1 This wrong. The comments have it right, and I will remove my downvote if you edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The struct does not add any functionality compared to a class except defaulting on public members. As such, none of that functionality is struct specific.